# Where is the Chrome newtab page located on my hard disk?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I've been searching through the Google directory in `C:\Users\Hobbit\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome` directory, and just can't seem to find the location of the new tab page. I've looked for other Google directories on my computer, and can't seem to find any others that might contain the new tab page.

Yes, I know that I can just use Right Click->Inspect Element (they disabled the View Source page), but I wanted to modify it, so I need the disk location.

The page must exist locally, because there's no way it contacts a server to get it.

---

I've searched until my head exploded (metaphorically, of course) on Google, and did not get any closer to solving it.

Comment: Have you tried using the Developer Tools for Chrome to check it out? It looks like it is built in to the browser itself when you examine some of the objects.

Comment: It exists locally, but that doesn't mean it exists as a *file*. It might be stored as a resource in some or other .dll, or it might be rendered completely by the program.

Comment: @BriGuy That's what I meant by Inspect Element in my OP.

Comment: grawity's right, Chrome's new tab page doesn't exist as a separate file. However there are lots of Chrome extensions that allow you to redirect to your own local pages or favourite sites when you open a new tab. You can use any of those and point to your own customised new tab page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is not a local file or even a resource somewhere. Instead, it is just a regular webpage somewhere on the Google domain: https://www.google.nl/_/chrome/newtab.

If you type this into your address bar, Chrome will clear it and show your recent tabs.

Comment: But when it's offline, I can still open and access the new tab page with no problem.